# Django atomic transaction not rolling back

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-2.7, django-models

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
with transaction.atomic():
    Model.objects.create(name="something")
    raise Exception
```

Since an exception is raised, this should mean that the transaction should roll back and the Model with name "something" should not exist.

However, if I query for `Model.objects.get(name="something")`, the object still exists in the db. Am I not understanding transactions correctly?

Comment: i test your code and don't get the same behavior, what database you use_? and is empty when your test_?

Comment: I'm currently at the same position, did you fix it? I'm using Postgres

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue recently and in my case it was because I was writing to a different database than the `"default"`. I have a custom database router that selects the database depending on the request but both read and writes happen on the same database.

*Note:* All my models use the same database during the request.

From the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/#:%7E:text=atomic%20takes%20a%20using%20argument%20which%20should%20be%20the%20name%20of%20a%20database.%20If%20this%20argument%20isn%E2%80%99t%20provided%2C%20Django%20uses%20the%20%22default%22%20database.), one must specify a database by providing `using="database_alias"` to the using block:

```py
database_alias = ... # Get the database alias by using the same logic as in the router
with transaction.atomic(using=database_alias):
    Model.objects.create(name="something")
    raise Exception
```